# Updating A Certain Column Values Within A User Defined Function In R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have the following piece of code to update a column in a dataframe in R with the median value. This works fine, but I would like to be able to call this as a function from other parts of the program, passing over other dataframes and columns.

```
medianVal <- median(df$column, na.rm = T)
df$column[is.na(df$column)] <- medianVal
```

The logic for the code I am attempting to use is Pass over the DataFrame and Column, Get the median Value, Update and return the dataframe

```
updateWithMedian <- function(DataFrame, Column)
{
  medianValue <- median(Column, na.rm = T)
  Column[is.na(DataFrame$Column)] <- medianValue
  return(DataFrame)
}
```

DataFrame[[Column]] in the function helps me identify the column, but I am still struggling to update the NA values to the median.

For example, the code

```
DataFrame[[Column]][is.na(DataFrame$Column)] <- medianValue
```

dosent feel like the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing notations here. If you use quoted column names, you cannot use the `dataframe$variable` kind of notation. Try that (untested) solution:

```r
updateWithMedian <- function(df, colname)
{
  medianValue <- median(df[,colname], na.rm = T)
  df[is.na(df[,colname]), colname] <- medianValue
  return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
updateWithMedian <- function(df, colname) {
       df %>%
           mutate_at(vars(colname), na.aggregate, FUN = median)
 }

updateWithMedian(df, "column")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that has worked perfectly. Just a follow on question, if I wanted to update the column value with the value of a different column in the same dataframe, what would be the correct step for it?

I have tried the the code below but this replaces the NAs in Col1 with the Col2 Name, but its the value I need.

```
updateWithMedian <- function(df, colname1, colname2)
{

  df[is.na(df[,colname1]), colname1] <- colname2
  return(df)
}
```